# How can I create search for one vocabulary?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, search

I create taxonomy called Cities. And I create vocabulary for this Paris,Lyon and ... .

How can I found for example "best day" search in search module for paris vocabulary When I'm in paris vocabulary page ( localhost/taxonomy/term/1 [paris vocabulary]) and just show titles have "best day" in "paris" ?

Comment: Can't provide an answer for the core search module, which is not very customizable. Use search api and if you want to do advanced stuff with taxonomy extend it with facets. Though in this case a simple view with an contextual filter for the taxonomy and an exposed filter for the search term might do it.

Comment: Thanks 4k4. how can I do this with views module? Please answer this to accept your answer.

Comment: You need to set up the things I mentioned in the comment before. Look for some tutorials for views and if you get stuck ask a specific question.